# How to provide an environmental variable for a service in windows

Tags: windows

We are running postgres database as a service in windows. How do I set specific environmental variables to such service.

Comment: You mean, You want to set PATH variable?

Comment: Not only PATH. I need to add few more environmental variables.

Answer (score -1):

If it's only about changing variables [that](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) should do the trick

Comment: I need to change only for specific process.

Comment: I don't get why answer was down voted. Question was not specific enough